# boost socket iostreams echo server with zlib compression sleeps until the connection will be closed

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-iostreams

I try to create simple echo server with zlib compression following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39918811/5441023) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39925695/5441023) examples.

My idea is to send some string now because I can convert POD types to string (`std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&pod), sizeof(pod))`) before sending when I will be sure the transport layer works.

And there is a problem here. Client compresses data, sends it and says data were sended but the server is blocked on data reading. I cannot understand why it happens.

I tried to use `operator<<` with `out.flush()`, also I tried to use `boost::iostreams::copy()`. The result is the same. The code example is (I use the same source file for server and client depending on args):

```cpp
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
using ip::tcp;

const unsigned short port = 9999;
const char host[] = "127.0.0.1";

void receive()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string(host), port);
    tcp::acceptor a(ctx, ep);

    tcp::iostream stream;
    a.accept(stream.socket());

    std::stringstream buffer;

    std::cout << "start session" << std::endl;

    try
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            {
                boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
                in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
                in.push(stream);

                std::cout << "start reading" << std::endl;

                // looks like server is blocked here
                boost::iostreams::copy(in, buffer);
            }

            std::cout << "data: " << buffer.str() << std::endl;

            {
                boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream out;
                out.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
                out.push(stream);

                boost::iostreams::copy(buffer, out);
            }

            std::cout << "Reply is sended" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch(const boost::iostreams::zlib_error &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << e.error() << '\n';
        stream.close();
    }
}

void send(const std::string &data)
{
    tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string(host), port);
    
    tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.connect(ep);

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << data;

    if (!stream)
    {
        std::cerr << "Cannot connect to " << host << ":" << port << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        {
            boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream out;
            out.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
            out.push(stream);

            out << buffer.str();
            out.flush();
        }

        std::cout << "sended: " << data << std::endl;
        buffer.str("");

        {
            boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
            in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
            in.push(stream);

            // looks like client is blocked here
            boost::iostreams::copy(in, buffer);
        }

        std::cout << "result: " << buffer.str() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const boost::iostreams::zlib_error &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1 && argv[1] ==  std::string("sender"))
        send("hello world");
    else
        receive();

    return 0;
}
```

First I start server and then I start client. The following output is produced:

Server

```
$ ./example
# now it waits while client will be accepted
start session
start reading
```

Client

```
$ ./example sender
sended: hello world
```

The programs are blocked with the output above. I guess the server still waits for data from client and it does not know the client sent all what it had.

If I close client with `Ctrl + C` then the output is following:

```
$ ./example
# now it waits while client will be accepted
start session
start reading
# now it is blocked until I press Ctrl + C
data: hello world
Reply is sended
start reading
zlib error-5
```

and

```
$ ./example sender
sended: hello world
^C
```

I guess the `zlib error-5` is because the server thinks the archive is incomplete.

**The expected behavior** is no blocking. The message must appear in the server program output when the client was started.

Why is the program blocked on reading? How can I fix it?

Comment: How is the receiver supposed to know how long the message is? You have to encode some kind of uncompressed message length to have any idea when to stop reading and actually decompress what you've received so far.

Comment: I think this should be done by `zlib_compressor`. If it gets data then it packs the data (we get an archive object) and the `tcp::iostream` object sends the archive object through network. And receiver gets the archive object with size, don't it? Correct me, please, if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iostreams::copy` does just that: it copies stream.

Compliments to your code. It's very readable :) It reminds me of this answer [Reading and writing files with boost iostream socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923638/reading-and-writing-files-with-boost-iostream-socket/39925695#39925695). The main difference is that that answer sends a *single* compressed blob and closes.

You're "right" that the decompressor knows when one compressed block is complete, but it doesn't decide that another will not follow.

So you need to add framing. The traditional way is to pass a length out-of-band. I've implemented the changes while also reducing code duplication by using IO manipulators.

```
template <typename T> struct LengthPrefixed {
    T _wrapped;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LengthPrefixed lp) ;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, LengthPrefixed lp) ;
};
```

And

```
template <typename T> struct ZLIB {
    T& data;
    ZLIB(T& ref) : data(ref){}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ZLIB z) ;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ZLIB z) ;
};
```

### `ZLIB` manipulator

This one mainly encapsulates the code that you duplicated between the sender/receiver:

```
template <typename T> struct ZLIB {
    T& data;
    ZLIB(T& ref) : data(ref){}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ZLIB z) {
        {
            boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream out;
            out.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
            out.push(os);
            out << z.data << std::flush;
        }
        return os.flush();
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ZLIB z) {
        boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
        in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
        in.push(is);

        std::ostringstream oss;
        copy(in, oss);
        z.data = oss.str();

        return is;
    }
};
```

> I made `T` templated so it can store `std::string&` or `std::string const&` depending on the need.

### `LengthPrefixed` manipulator

This manipulator doesn't care what is being serialized, but will simply prefix it with the effective length on-the-wire:

```
template <typename T> struct LengthPrefixed {
    T _wrapped;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LengthPrefixed lp) {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << lp._wrapped;
        auto on_the_wire = std::move(oss).str();

        debug << "Writing length " << on_the_wire.length() << std::endl;
        return os << on_the_wire.length() << "\n" << on_the_wire << std::flush;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, LengthPrefixed lp) {
        size_t len;
        if (is >> std::noskipws >> len && is.ignore(1, '\n')) {
            debug << "Reading length " << len << std::endl;

            std::string on_the_wire(len, '\0');
            if (is.read(on_the_wire.data(), on_the_wire.size())) {
                std::istringstream iss(on_the_wire);
                iss >> lp._wrapped;
            }
        }
        return is;
    }
};
```

We add a subtlety: by storing a reference or value depending on what we are constructed with we can also accept temporaries (like the ZLIB manipulator):

```
template <typename T> LengthPrefixed(T&&) -> LengthPrefixed<T>;
template <typename T> LengthPrefixed(T&) -> LengthPrefixed<T&>;
```

> I didnt' think to make the `ZLIB` manipulator equally generic. So I leave that as an exorcism for the reader

### DEMO PROGRAM

Combining these two, you can write the sender/receiver simply as:

```
void server() {
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string(host), port);
    tcp::acceptor a(ctx, ep);

    tcp::iostream stream;
    a.accept(stream.socket());

    std::cout << "start session" << std::endl;

    for (std::string data; stream >> LengthPrefixed{ZLIB{data}};) {
        std::cout << "data: " << std::quoted(data) << std::endl;
        stream << LengthPrefixed{ZLIB{data}} << std::flush;
    }
}

void client(std::string data) {
    tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string(host), port);
    tcp::iostream stream(ep);

    stream << LengthPrefixed{ZLIB{data}} << std::flush;
    std::cout << "sent: " << std::quoted(data) << std::endl;

    stream >> LengthPrefixed{ZLIB{data}};
    std::cout << "result: " << std::quoted(data) << std::endl;
}
```

Indeed, it prints:

```
reader: start session
sender: Writing length 19
reader: Reading length 19
sender: sent: "hello world"
reader: data: "hello world"
reader: Writing length 19
sender: Reading length 19
sender: result: "hello world"
```

### Complete Listing

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
using ip::tcp;

const unsigned short port = 9999;
const char host[] = "127.0.0.1";

#ifdef DEBUG
    std::ostream debug(std::cerr.rdbuf());
#else
    std::ostream debug(nullptr);
#endif

template <typename T> struct LengthPrefixed {
    T _wrapped;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LengthPrefixed lp) {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << lp._wrapped;
        auto on_the_wire = std::move(oss).str();

        debug << "Writing length " << on_the_wire.length() << std::endl;
        return os << on_the_wire.length() << "\n" << on_the_wire << std::flush;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, LengthPrefixed lp) {
        size_t len;
        if (is >> std::noskipws >> len && is.ignore(1, '\n')) {
            debug << "Reading length " << len << std::endl;

            std::string on_the_wire(len, '\0');
            if (is.read(on_the_wire.data(), on_the_wire.size())) {
                std::istringstream iss(on_the_wire);
                iss >> lp._wrapped;
            }
        }
        return is;
    }
};

template <typename T> LengthPrefixed(T&&) -> LengthPrefixed<T>;
template <typename T> LengthPrefixed(T&) -> LengthPrefixed<T&>;

template <typename T> struct ZLIB {
    T& data;
    ZLIB(T& ref) : data(ref){}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ZLIB z) {
        {
            boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream out;
            out.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
            out.push(os);
            out << z.data << std::flush;
        }
        return os.flush();
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ZLIB z) {
        boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
        in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
        in.push(is);

        std::ostringstream oss;
        copy(in, oss);
        z.data = oss.str();

        return is;
    }
};

void server() {
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string(host), port);
    tcp::acceptor a(ctx, ep);

    tcp::iostream stream;
    a.accept(stream.socket());

    std::cout << "start session" << std::endl;

    for (std::string data; stream >> LengthPrefixed{ZLIB{data}};) {
        std::cout << "data: " << std::quoted(data) << std::endl;
        stream << LengthPrefixed{ZLIB{data}} << std::flush;
    }
}

void client(std::string data) {
    tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string(host), port);
    tcp::iostream stream(ep);

    stream << LengthPrefixed{ZLIB{data}} << std::flush;
    std::cout << "sent: " << std::quoted(data) << std::endl;

    stream >> LengthPrefixed{ZLIB{data}};
    std::cout << "result: " << std::quoted(data) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char**) {
    try {
        if (argc > 1)
            client("hello world");
        else
            server();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: *I made `T` templated so it can store `std::string&` or `std::string const&` depending on the need*.. If I'm not wrong, it can store any type that overloads `operator<<` and `operator>>`, can't it?

Comment: Also you said *but it doesn't decide that another will not follow*. If I get it clearly, the `operator>>(std::istream &is, LengthPrefixed lp)` helps the stream to understand how much data it have to read. Correct me, please, if I'm wrong.

Comment: I accept your answer because I agree with you. Your answer is more generic and can be more helpful for people with the same questions.

Comment: _"If I get it clearly, the operator>>(std::istream &is, LengthPrefixed lp) helps the stream to understand how much data it have to read"_ Precisely. In addition we feed it into a length-limited stream.

Comment: I would suggest [boost::iostreams::restrict](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/restrict.html) were it not that I know of [issues when used recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188393/boost-restrct-twice-after-reading-some-data-gave-wrong-result/63194390#63194390) that I'm not confident would not interfere, which is why I "tolerate" the extra copy through `std::stringstream`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by using of `boost::serialization` with the following steps:

1. First of all I moved zipping to functions like this:

```
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

namespace my {
std::string compress(const std::string &data)
{
    std::stringstream input, output;

    input << data;

    io::filtering_ostream io_out;
    io_out.push(io::zlib_compressor());
    io_out.push(output);

    io::copy(input, io_out);

    return output.str();
}

std::string decompress(const std::string &data)
{
    std::stringstream input, output;

    input << data;

    io::filtering_istream io_in;
    io_in.push(io::zlib_decompressor());
    io_in.push(input);

    io::copy(io_in, output);

    return output.str();
}
} // namespace my
```

2. Then I created a wrapper for string buffer like this (following the tutorial from [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)):

```
class Package
{
public:
    Package(const std::string &buffer) : buffer(buffer) {}

private:
    std::string buffer;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int)
    {
        ar & buffer;
    }

};
```

3. And at last I appended serialization after reading and before sending.

```
/**
 * receiver
 */
Package request;

{
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(*stream);
    ia >> request;
}

std::string data = my::decompress(request.buffer);

// do something with data

Package response(my::compress(data));

{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(*stream);
    oa << response;
}

/**
 * sender
 */
std::string data = "hello world";
Package package(my::compress(data));

// send request
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(*m_stream);
    oa << package;
}

// waiting for a response
{
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(*m_stream);
    ia >> package;
}

// decompress response buffer
result = my::decompress(package.get_buffer());
```

Comment: You realize that this sidesteps the problem by double-buffering using `my:::compress`/`my::decompress` and Boost Serialization has nothing to do with it, right? In fact, that's basically the same solution I suggested, though my answer is more generic.

Comment: @sehe, Boost.Serialization is used as a tool that just serialize the `Package` object and the object is already packed using `my::compress` in sender and the reverse actions in receiver